# Add pandas data frames together, ignoring string-based column, and adding on index, with fill value 0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm trying to add two pandas data frames together on an index and ignoring the non-numerical columns. I've added a minimal reproducible example here.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"Surname" : ["Adams", "Sallings", "Teezle"], "Name" : ["Frank", "Jim", "John"], "Age" : [23, 53, 33]}).set_index("Surname")
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"Surname" : ["Adams", "Sallings", "Watting"], "Name" : ["Frank", "Jim", "John"], "Age" : [23, 53, 33]}).set_index("Surname")
df3 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"Surname" : ["Adams", "Sallings", "Teezle", "Watting"], "Name" : ["Frank", "Jim", "John", "John"], "Age" : [46, 106, 33, 33]}).set_index("Surname")
```

In these data frames, `Surname` is a unique identifier and I would like to add up the data frames based on `Surname`, ignoring the `Name` column, but adding up entries in the `Age` column, using `fill_value = 0` if there is an entry in one index that isn't in the other.

I have been attempting to do this using `df.add` but setting `fill_value = 0` in this throws an error since I can't concatenate 0 to the end of a string. It is not clear how to make this ignore the non-numerical columns and get my desired output. How to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
# for some reason, df3 doesn't have the Surname as the index, so we remedy that
df3.set_index("Surname", inplace=True)


df1._get_numeric_data().add(df2._get_numeric_data(), fill_value=0).add(df3._get_numeric_data(), fill_value=0)

# Output:
            Age
Surname        
Adams      92.0
Sallings  212.0
Teezle     66.0
Watting    66.0
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
df3.set_index("Surname",inplace=True)
df4 = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3],axis=0).groupby(["Surname"]).agg(Total_Age=('Age', 'sum'))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

We can use parameters `skipna=False, numeric_only=True` of the `sum` method:

```py
# input data
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"Surname" : ["Adams", "Sallings", "Teezle"], "Name" : ["Frank", "Jim", "John"], "Age" : [23, 53, 33]}).set_index("Surname")
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"Surname" : ["Adams", "Sallings", "Watting"], "Name" : ["Frank", "Jim", "John"], "Age" : [23, 53, 33]}).set_index("Surname")
df3 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"Surname" : ["Adams", "Sallings", "Teezle", "Watting"], "Name" : ["Frank", "Jim", "John", "John"], "Age" : [46, 106, 33, 33]}).set_index("Surname")

# output result
total = (
    # after concatenation we'll have 3 columns named as 'Age' and 3 as 'Name'
    pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis='columns')

    # can be skipped if there's no other numeric columns except 'Age'
    .get('Age')   

    # with skipna=False we obtain nan + number = nan
    # with skipna=True we obtain nan + number = number
    # numeric_only can be skipped if .get('Age') is used
    .sum('columns', skipna=False, numeric_only=True)   

    # put 0 where nan occures
    # in case if skipna=False on the previous step
    .fillna(0)    
)

print(total)
```

```
Surname
Adams        92.0
Sallings    212.0
Teezle        0.0
Watting       0.0
dtype: float64
```